# Problem calling a .SQL file via a batch file due to use of single and double quotes in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I have a script that executes fine inside SQL Server 2017 query window. I want to run the script using a batch file so I can export the results to a file.

I am getting errors when I call the query using a batch file. I know it has to do with how Windows DOS handles single and double quotes. I have played around with adding single and or double quotes around the data and around the existing single and double quotes but with no luck. I have included below my batch file and the query I need to run.

BATCH CONTENTS (Line 9 is the line that executes the SQL statement by calling itemexport.sql file)

```
cd %UserProfile%\Documents\Tend\Reports
set bd=%UserProfile%\Documents\Tend\Reports\Export
echo *****%date%@%time% - Exporting Item List >> %bd%\item_export.log
echo off
set hh=%time:~0,2%
if "%time:~0,1%"==" " set hh=0%hh:~1,1%  
set dt=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_%hh:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
echo on
sqlcmd -S%1 -E -i"itemexport.sql" >> %bd%\item_export-%dt%.csv
echo *****%date%@%time% - Item Export complete >> %bd%\item_export.log
```

This is the SQL QUERY I am Executing.  This file is named itemexport.sql

```
SELECT 
    ITEM.NAME, UPC, ITEM_DEPARTMENT.NAME AS DEPARTMENT, 
    CAST(ON_HAND_QTY AS decimal(18, 0)) AS "ON HAND QTY", 
    CAST(ITEM.PRICING AS XML).value(N'(/prices[@type="Level"]/item[@level="A"])[1]/@price', N'DECIMAL(14,2)') AS "RETAIL PRICE"
FROM    
    ITEM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ITEM_DEPARTMENT ON ITEM_DEPARTMENT.RECORD_KEY = ITEM.ITEM_DEPARTMENT_RECORD_KEY
WHERE
    (ITEM_DEPARTMENT.NAME IN ('BEER','CIDER','WINE'))
    AND (ITEM.CAN_SELL = 1)
    AND (ON_HAND_QTY > 0)
GROUP BY  
    ITEM.NAME, SKU, UPC, ITEM_DEPARTMENT_RECORD_KEY, 
    ITEM_DEPARTMENT.NAME, ITEM.ON_HAND_QTY, ITEM.PRICING
ORDER BY 
    ITEM_DEPARTMENT.NAME
```

This is the part of the select Statement that I am getting errors when using the batch file

```
CAST(ITEM.PRICING AS XML).value(N'(/prices[@type="Level"]/item[@level="A"])[1]/@price', N'DECIMAL(14,2)')
```

This is the error that I receive....
"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server BYND5CG8470J1H, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Level'."

If I comment out that cast statement the items are exported but that "Retail Price" column is Null for each item because the line I commented out is supposed to parse the price out of a line like `<prices type="Level"><item level="A" price="1.25" /></prices>`

Here is a sample of the output when running the query in SQL.
[image]

Any help formatting the cast statement would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My database is MS SQL Server 2017

Comment: What errors do you get? Perhaps you need to change your `sqlcmd` command line to `sqlcmd -S"%~1" -E -i"itemexport.sql"` and, in general, the redirection part to `>> "%bd%\item_export-%dt%.csv"`…

Comment: Please add some information to your question describing the type of errors you're seeing when the query is executed from the batch file.

Comment: This is the error I am getting---Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server BYND5CG8470J1H, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Level'.

Comment: If I comment out that cast statement the items are exported but that "Retail Price" column is Null for each item because the line I commented out is supposed to parse the price out of a line like <prices type="Level"><item level="A" price="1.25" /></prices>

Comment: is quoted_identifier on in the itemexport.sql (it must be on for xml methods)?  `set quoted_identifier on; ...SELECT  ITEM.NAME,...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if disabling variable substitution with the parameter `-x` helps with your sqlcmd (see [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5132/issues-with-sqlcmd-when-using-special-characters/)) but if the issue is limited to your CAST(parse) statement, can you simply make that a UDF and bypass the error altogether?

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION parsePrice(@in varchar(max))
RETURNS decimal(14,2) AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(@in AS XML).value(N'(/prices[@type="Level"]/item[@level="A"])[1]/@price', N'DECIMAL(14,2)') ;
END
```

And then your query becomes

```
SELECT 
    ITEM.NAME, UPC, ITEM_DEPARTMENT.NAME AS DEPARTMENT, 
    CAST(ON_HAND_QTY AS decimal(18, 0)) AS "ON HAND QTY", 
    dbo.parsePrice(ITEM.PRICING) AS "RETAIL PRICE"
FROM    
    ITEM 
...
```

Comment: Creating a function to parse the price was the way to go.  Thank you for this suggestion.